# Break out of current scope

Tags: programming, workflow

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
{
    Instruction 1

    If condition -> break

    Instruction 2
}
Do some more stuff
```

Is there a way to do something like this in LaTeX? I am referring to the `break` part.

In other words I am searching for a way to break out of the current scope in LaTeX. In the above example that'd mean that if `condition` is `true` then `Instruction 2` shouldn't get executed because LaTeX breaks out of the code and continues with `Do some more stuff`.

Comment: There is not. At least not how other programming languages do it. One usual way to achieve this is to define a macro which reads everthing up to an endmarker as argument and then discards it. Goes like `\ifnum\x<3 \expandafter\discardtillmarker\fi` where `\discardtillmarker` is define using `\long\def\discardtillmarker#1\marker{}`. Here `\marker` can be any macro or even special character.

Comment: Well that's something one can work with... If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The given answer is good for the problem as set. Please, add some more information about your real aim.

Comment: There actually isn't a concrete real problem... I was just wondering if something like this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

This will execute `Instruction 1`, check the `<condition>` and if the condition is false, execute `Instruction 2`. Then it will proceed to `Do some more stuff`.

```
Instruction 1

\if<condition>
  \relax% does nothing
\else
  Instruction 2
\fi

Do some more stuff
```

Now the tricky part is you want in the `<condition>`...

Comment: Although this would solve the problem for this simple example this does not answer the original question... The problem with this approach is when one has multiple nested scopes and it would be quite messy to do this with of-statements...

Comment: @Raven It'd be helpful if you could provide an example that better represents your current situation then, so that users can give better answers.

Comment: It was more intended as a general question as I am currently learning how to write tex packages and I thought this might come in handy some time and because I didn't find anything about it on the web I decided to ask here... The answer has actually already been given as a comment on my question...